# QListView selectionModel not sending selectionChanged signal

Tags: c++, qt, listview, signals

I have an interface with two `QListViews`, where the left determines what is displayed in the right:
[image: layout]

To update the list on the right, I have the following function:

```
void CodePlug::handleSelectionChanged()
{
    QModelIndex portIndex = ui->listPorts->currentIndex();
    QString portItemText = portIndex.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    ui->listPlugs->setModel(ListModelFromMap(plugs[portItemText]));
    currentPort = portItemText;
    qDebug(currentPort.toStdString().data());
}
```

and it's connected to the selectionChanged signal here:

```
CodePlug::CodePlug(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::CodePlug)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->listPorts->setModel(ListModelFromMap(ports));
    QModelIndex portIndex = ui->listPlugs->currentIndex();
    QString portItemText = portIndex.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    ui->listPlugs->setModel(ListModelFromMap(plugs[portItemText]));

    connect(ui->listPorts->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QItemSelection,QItemSelection)), this, SLOT(handleSelectionChanged()));
}
```

However, changing the selected item by either the keyboard or the mouse never triggers `handleSelectionChanged()`. It doesn't generate any errors, it just doesn't do anything. Could anybody give me an idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, and it was silly.

When a new item was added to the list, I was calling `setModel()` on `listPorts`, which of course broke the connection. I suspect there is a better way to handle the change, so I'll try and fix that but for now, I'm reconnecting every time the model is changed.

Answer (score 2):

Posible errors:

1. Is your function `handleSelectionChanged()` defined as private/public slot?
2. Is your default [SelectionMode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum) `QAbstractItemView::NoSelection`?

Try to force a single/multiple selection:

```
ui->listPorts->setSelectionMode(QItemSelectionModel::::SingleSelection)
```

Check if your QObject::connect is working well:

```
if (!connect(ui->listPorts->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QItemSelection,QItemSelection)), this, SLOT(handleSelectionChanged()))) 
     qDebug() << "Something wrong :(";
```

Comment: handleSelectionChanged is defined as a public slot, and works with other signals. The default SelectionMode is SingleSelection. The connect does seem to be working.

Comment: Common issue, you should connect your signal/slot after initializing the model of your list.

Answer (score 1):

Connection looks ok to me. You sure you are not seeing any runtime errors? Below, few things to check if they help.

1) Check that you have added `Q_OBJECT` macro to your `CodePlug` class header. If not, add it and run qmake again.

```
class CodePlug : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
```

2) Check that you have defined `handleSelectionChanged` as a slot.

```
private slots:
    void handleSelectionChanged();
```

3) Check if `connect` actually succeeds by checking what it returns

```
bool ret = connect(ui->listPorts->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QItemSelection,QItemSelection)), this, SLOT(handleSelectionChanged()));
```

4) Test if [currentChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#currentChanged) signal is triggered by connecting it to e.g. handleCurrentChanged slot.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these seem to be the cause. I have alternated trying currentChanged and selectionChanged, both returned true, but neither triggered the function.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're not changing the selection, you're changing the current/active item. Connect to the `activated(const QModelIndex &index)` signal instead.